# Connecting to Second Elastic IP Address assigned to an ENI on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, routing, amazon-vpc

I have a single ENI connected to a t2.micro EC2 instance.

It has an Elastic IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx associated with the "primary private IP address".

I added a "secondary private IP Address" to the ENI and associated it with another Elastic IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

All ICMP traffic is allowed on the security group associated with the ENI.

I am able to ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx but I am unable to ping yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.

The EC2 Operating System is Debian Buster.

How do I configure so that yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy is accessible from the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "secondary private IP address" through the AWS interface will add the IP Address to the Operating System interface such as "eth0" in Linux **effectively only for AMIs from AWS.**

For private AMIs such as Debian Buster, the "secondary private IP address" added through the AWS interface **should also be manually added to the Operating system interface such as "eth0"** by executing command inside the EC2 instance.

Eg:

If the Secondary IP Address added through the AWS interface is **"172.16.10.2"**

and

the Network interface of the Operating System is **"eth0"**

then the command to be executed is:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 172.16.10.2 dev eth0
```

In general,the command for Linux would be

```
ip addr add <ip_address> dev <interface>
```

To make the change persist after reboot the easiest way is to add a corn entry for root.

Use the command

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

and create an entry such as

```
# Add Secondary Private Ip Address to 'eth0'
@reboot ip addr add 172.31.17.171 dev eth0
```

Reboot the EC2 instance and check if the entry persists with the command

```
$ip a
```

For other Unix-like systems, there are corresponding commands and configurations to add more than one IP address (aliases) to the interface.

eg: [OpenBSD](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html#Setup.aliases) , [FreeBSD](https://web.archive.org/web/20210209143455/https://major.io/2007/08/08/adding-ip-aliases-in-freebsd/)